# Data from uploaded file

Tags: php, html, mysql, cakephp

I have a code with what can be the number of files uploaded in to folder and I want these files name, size and URL in to database, but my Controller is not working. (Im using CakePHP framework). I want to add these files data what Im uploading in to database (all files data) and I got error.

Error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: tmp_namā€ā€‹ā€ā€‹e [APP\Controller\UploadFilesController.php, line 24]
```

**My Controller**

```
public function uploadFile() {
        $filename = '';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {           // checks for the post values
                $uploadData = $this->request->data;
                //print_r($this->request->data); die;
                foreach($uploadData as $file){
                $filename = basename($file['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                    return false;
                } 
                echo "Sa sisestasid faili: $filename<br>";
            }
             foreach($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] as $file){
                if (!empty($this->request->data)  && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['tmp_nam‌​‌​e'])) {  //THIS IS LINE 24
                    $fileData = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['size']);
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['name'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['size'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData;
                    $this->UploadFile->create();
                    $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
                }
            }
         }
     }    
    }
```

**And here is my View file:**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('uploadFile', array( 'type' => 'file'));
?>

    <div class="input_fields_wrap">

        <label for="uploadFilefiles"></label>
        <input type="file" name="data[]" id="uploadFilefiles">

    </div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button">+</button> <br><br>

    <form name="frm1" method="post" onsubmit="return greeting()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php
echo $this->Html->script('addFile');
```

If it is necessary I can also add `AddFile` script.

Here is my table (**upload_files**) structure:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, this is the best way to do this :

```
public function uploadFile() {
    $filename = '';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {           // checks for the post values
            $uploadData = $this->request->data ['UploadFile']['file_upload'];
            //print_r($this->request->data); die;
            foreach($uploadData as $file){
                $filename = basename($file['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                    return false;
                } 
                echo "Sa sisestasid faili: $filename<br>";

                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $file['name'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $file['size'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $file['tmp_name'];
                    $this->UploadFile->create();
                    $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
            }           
        }
    }
```

I tried this in my host and its working.

Comment: You may award your bounty in 22 hours.  Sorry

Comment: It's okay. I'm glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

You change in view:

```
<input type="file" name="data[UploadFile][file_upload][]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="AuthorAuthorImage">
```

And controller you get

```
$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']
```

This data is array with format:

```
array (
[0] => Array
(
    [name] => 0.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php5896.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 55125
)

[1] => Array
(
    [name] => 1.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php5897.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 49613
)

[2] => Array
(
    [name] => 1-16.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php58A7.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 1545337
)
)
```

Good luck!

Comment: ye, but I dont use in input this multiple, I use script what makes new inputs.

Comment: You can use <input type="file" name="data[UploadFile][file_upload][]" />

Comment: this dont like this line `if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['tmp_name'])) {` I get error : `Undefined index: tmp_name [APP\Controller\UploadFilesController.php, line 23]`

Comment: If you upload multiple files, $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] is array, you should use foreach ($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] as $k => file)

Comment: It works if I change input name from `data[UploadFile][file_upload][]` to `data[UploadFile][file_upload]`. Is it possible to change controller from `$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']` to something like this `$this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] ['[]']`

Answer (score 1):

As tungbk29 said, $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] is array so you should change the foreach code like this

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'])) {            
    foreach($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload'] as $file){
         if (is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
                    $fileData = fread(fopen($file['tmp_name'], "r"), $file['size']);
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $file['name'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $file['size'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $file['tmp_name'];
                    $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData;
                    $this->UploadFile->create();
                    $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
          }
     }
}
```

Hope it helps again!

Comment: I got 3 same warnings, `Warning (2): is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [APP\Controller\UploadFilesController.php, line 25]`

Comment: In to database I get nothing

Comment: If there is no error showing, you have to debug variables to see what is happening

Comment: I debugged `var_dump($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']);` after this IF sentence and I got all 3 files, but why no querys ?

Comment: why don't you see validation error var_dump($this->UploadFile->validationErrors); after save function?

Comment: I put this `var_dump($this->UploadFile->validationErrors);` after the save function and I get 3 empty arrays, but if I use this `var_dump($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']);` after the save function then I got 3x3 not empty arrays

Comment: It is strange. if there is no validation error, the data should be saved in database.

Comment: But its not saving, I got empty database

Comment: It might not be related to the saving but I didn't see the data column in the database screenshot.

Comment: Ye I deleted this line, but this is changing nothing