# Only one file data going in to database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hello I want uploaded files data in to database, but I got only one file data. All these files datas  trying to go in to database but they use all same ID and thanks to this its writing this line over. How I get these all datas in to database ?

**What Im trying to do :**

```
            if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'])) {
            $fileData = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['size']);
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['size'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData;
            $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
            }
            if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'])) {
            $fileData1 = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['size']);
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['size'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData1;
            $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
            }
            if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'])) {
            $fileData2 = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['size']);
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['size'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'];
            $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData2;
            $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
            }
```

I want to insert 3 files data in to database, but I get only one file data.

**and result :**

```
1   INSERT INTO `kontaktid`.`upload_files` (`name`, `size`, `URL`) VALUES ('add.JPG', 61020, 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php75DF.tmp')
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34
3   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34
4   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34
5   UPDATE `kontaktid`.`upload_files` SET `name` = 'empty rows.JPG', `size` = 73534, `URL` = 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php75F0.tmp' WHERE `kontaktid`.`upload_files`.`id` = '34'
6   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34
7   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34 
8   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `kontaktid`.`upload_files` AS `UploadFile` WHERE `UploadFile`.`id` = 34
9   UPDATE `kontaktid`.`upload_files` SET `name` = 'vardump.JPG', `size` = 79107, `URL` = 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php75F1.tmp' WHERE `kontaktid`.`upload_files`.`id` = '34'
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Consider not storing the files in the database itself, instead store the location of the files which you store in the server/drive. Also, how is your id mechanism implemented? Do you have auto_increment on the id column?

Comment: ye , I have AI on the id column

Comment: From the manual: `When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call clear().` So I think, you need to call clear, after save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every save, you should use `$this->UploadFile->create();`, other wise it will only save one. so it'd be like this:

```
        if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileData = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['size']);
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['size'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0']['tmp_name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData;
        $this->UploadFile->create();
        $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
        }
        if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileData1 = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['size']);
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['size'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData1;
        $this->UploadFile->create();
        $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
        }
        if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileData2 = fread(fopen($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['size']);
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['size'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['URL'] = $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'];
        $this->request->data['UploadFile']['data'] = $fileData2;
        $this->UploadFile->create();
        $this->UploadFile->save($this->request->data);
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice Thanks ! But If I upload only 1 file then I got these errors : `Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1 [APP\Controller\UploadFilesController.php, line 33]
Notice (8): Undefined offset: 2 [APP\Controller\UploadFilesController.php, line 42]`

Comment: How do I get rid of them ?

Comment: it might be because of undefined offset of ['0'] in $this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0'], I don't know the line where you are having errors so I couldn't tell exactly

Comment: this line is 33 `if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_name'])) {` and this line is 42 `if (!empty($this->request->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['2']['tmp_name'])) {` I get these errors because I dont use these lines when Im uploading only 1 file, when I upload 2 files then I got one error and when I upload 3files then I got zero error.

Comment: This wasnt my question before, but I hope u can help me :)

Comment: ok you can add isset($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['0/1/2']['tmp_nam‌​e']) on all if logics like this: if (!empty($this->request->data) && isset($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_nam‌​e']) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['UploadFile']['file_upload']['1']['tmp_nam‌​e'])) ...

Comment: Its not working, if I change these lines then It not inserting in to database . I cant do new question in 90min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68636/discussion-between-miheretab-alemu-and-frantsium).

Comment: If u want points and want to help, then check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856966/data-from-uploaded-file